# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
NUM_SQ = 8
empty = 1
board = []
for sq in range(NUM_SQ):
    board.append[empty]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NUM_SQ = 8
empty = 1
board = []
for sq in range(NUM_SQ):
    board.append(empty)
```

Функции пишутся в круглых скобках.

Comment: Спасибо, как бестолочь прицепился к индексу и забыл про основы методов

Comment: Не за что, бывает. Порекомендую в будующем разъяснять проблему и если ответ верный поставьте галочку.

Comment: Хорошо, я тут нубас и не знаю куда и какую галочку нужно ставить, если ткнешь носом - изи.

Comment: Рядом с вопросом есть стрелки и ниже серая галочка, она показывает что ответ правильный, если ее нажать она станет зеленой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer тут подробно